# Leaflet: edit popupcontent

Tags: leaflet, popup, update, leaflet-draw

Im looking foward to create a mobile leaflet application to collect data.

First i use the L.locate-control plugin to get my current location:

```
L.control.locate({
strings: {
    title: "current position"
},  
locateOptions: {
           timeout: 10000}                                                        
}).addTo(map);
```

Then i initialize a button with the L.EasyButton plugin to store the current location with a marker and add it to my layerGroup (places):

```
var places = new L.layerGroup();

L.easyButton('fa fa-thumb-tack', function(){
map.addOneTimeEventListener('locationfound', function (event) {
var marker = L.marker(event.latlng, {icon: smallIcon2}).addTo(places);
});
}).addTo(map);
```

In the end im using :

```
 document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {

        var data = places.toGeoJSON();


        var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));


        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
        document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.geojson');
    }
```

to export the marker position as a geojson data.

Everything works well so far!

Now im looking for a way to edit the popupcontent of a marker by clicking the marker and adding a value/text with the keyboard. Similiar to the way it is possible with leaflet.draw.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: i added a textarea and set the popup of the marker to the content value of the textarea.

Heres the final code for implemanting the features i was looking for:

```
L.easyButton('fa fa-thumb-tack', function(){

map.addOneTimeEventListener('locationfound', function (event) {
var marker = L.marker(event.latlng, {icon: smallIcon2}).addTo(places).addTo(map).on('click', onClick);
marker.properties = {};
var feature = marker.feature = marker.feature || {};
feature.type = "Feature";
feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
var content = document.createElement("textarea");

content.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    feature.properties["Name"] = content.value;
});
marker.on("popupopen", function () {
    feature.properties["Name"] = content.value;
  content.focus();
});
marker.bindPopup(content).openPopup();
```

With the textarea field implemantation im able to add a value to the marker. By defining the feature.properties and setting its value to `content.value` im able to save the value to the marker. When exporting to geoJson it will be exported too.